# Spark structured streaming multiple applications joined by Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have two Spark structured streaming applications. The first makes some windowing aggregations and outputs to Kafka in "update" mode. The second reads this Kafka stream and does some further processing and again outputs in "update" mode.

Will the second application reading the Kafka stream read in the most up to date data?

Comment: what does "update" mode mean when you are writing to Kafka output? you are not writing to a table, you are sending messages, right?

Comment: This is the mode Spark outputs to the Kafka sink: "Update Mode - Only the rows that were updated in the Result Table since the last trigger will be written to the external storage (available since Spark 2.1.1)"

Comment: but I thought output to kafka is immutable. What are you updating?

Comment: The Spark structured streaming docs state that it is possible to output to a [Kafka sink](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-sinks)
 as described in my previous comment, [this section](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html) describes how to integrate Kafka with structured streaming. I am unsure on the technical details of how this is implemented.

Comment: I see. this example here (https://databricks.com/blog/2017/04/04/real-time-end-to-end-integration-with-apache-kafka-in-apache-sparks-structured-streaming.html)  uses update mode with kafka. What this means is it only sends rows that were updated rather than whole rows (even non-updated ones) which is what you want. It doesn't update anything on Kafka side. On the other side, you will be reading multiple values for the rows and you need to pick the latest value. Given that you disregard old values and pick most recent, you are guaranteed to read most up to date data.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I had read suggestions to push to kafka then read the resultant stream in order to get around there not being multi aggregation support in structured stream. I will spend some more time investigating this.